# What is the best way to implement screens that always have AppBar and BottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have 3 screens - `home`, `friends` and `profile`. I want an `AppBar`and `BottomNavigationBar` to be always present in all my screens. Right now, I have the `AppBar` and `BottomNavigationBar` defined inside a `Scaffold` in the `main.dart` file. Whenever an option is tapped on `BottomNavigationBar`, the `Scaffold` body is replaced with the content of the screen of choice.

**main.dart:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
        child: _pageOptions[_selectedPage],
      ),
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      currentIndex: _selectedPage,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          _selectedPage = index;
        });
      },
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.people), title: Text('Friends')),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text('Profile'))
      ],
    ),
  ),
  routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    '/home': (BuildContext context) => Home(),
    '/friends': (BuildContext context) => Friends(),
  },
);
}
```

Now, I have a custom `avatar` widget that I have reused in `home` screen. On clicking the `avatar`, I want to display the `friends` screen. I tried this code inside an `onTap` method in `avatar`:

```
{Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/friends')},
```

**friends.dart:**

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Text('Friends'),
    );
}
```

On tapping `avatar`, I am getting the `friends` screen, but everything else is lost (`AppBar`, `BottomNavigationBar` etc).

How do I achieve this? Should I be returning a scaffold with `AppBar`, `BottomNavigationBar` etc. from all 3 of my screens? Does that negatively affect performance? Or is there a way to do this just by replacing the body of the `Scaffold` in `main.dart`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need to return a scaffold with an appbar in all the three screens. You can put the appbar in a separate statelesswidget class and use it in all the three scaffolds. Same for bottom navigation bar. You can try to keep the returning widget in build method 'const'. Will not be possible for appbar since title will be varying. It won't get rebuilt so no worries on performance.